# How do I subscribe to security advisory notifications?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

As a user of the community edition, where can I subscribe to a mailing list or RSS feed for announcements of security advisories?  I understand I can visit https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Security+Advisories periodically and see what changed but a push of this information from WSO2 would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited]

WSO2 sends email notifications to all the users that have downloaded the affected products while doing public security announcements. WSO2 uses the email address that an individual has provided at the product distribution download time. These emails will be sent shortly after the advisories are listed on the page you've pointed out.

Comment: Thanks.  To let you and WSO2 know, that communication channel is spotty.  It would be helpful if WSO2 or the community had a dedicated channel specifically for security announcements so the marketing isn't mixed in with the higher priority security announcements.